# What do you call someone who's job is to guard or watch vehicles?

Tags: word-request

What do you call someone whose job is to guard or watch government-owned vehicles? Or any vehicle.

Comment: A "guard"?  We are talking about someone different from the *driver*, right?  Can you provide some more description about what you might do in such a job?

Comment: A [**sentry**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sentry) is a soldier stationed to keep guard or to control access to a place. There is no emphasis on vehicles, or civilians, although one might be called a [**security guard**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/security_guard).

Comment: Perhaps a [**minder**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/minder) which although commonly used for someone who protects people, a minder might protect property too. "A person whose job it is to look after someone or something."

Comment: I've never met someone whose job was exclusively to guard or watch vehicles. Is there a specific word for this job in your native language? Could you share it with us?